# How to change Zimbra Welcome page

Tags: email-server, login, zimbra, xml

I have configured a zimbra mail server. It is working fine. But I want to make one of my own html page as welcome file before login page.
I have tried to edit the web.xml file but it is of no use. please can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure if my answer is useful, but wouldn't you look for answer at

- (active forums) community.zimbra.com, or
- (archived forums) forums.zimbra.com

For example:

- Changing ZWC (Zimbra Web Client) Theme Colors and Logo in [zimbra administration_guide](http://www.zimbra.com/docs/ne/5.0.19/administration_guide/branding_skins_steps_5x.17.1.htm)
- Zimbra Forum: [Changing Zimbra 7.0 Login Screen](http://forums.zimbra.com/showthread.php?t=47686)

> The default theme for zimbraAdmin, zimbra and zimlets are all set using
>   a config file for the web application.
>
> look in jetty/etc/zimbra.web.xml.in

See! Zimbra stores initial parameters in `*.in` files. These files are templates which will be populated with actual values on every restart of ZCS. So, to make your changes permanent, you must modify `.in` file, corresponding to file you want to change.

I found this when attempted to modify ZCS' postfix parameters. `.in-files` have zimbra:zimbra:600 permissions, so you must use `sudo su - zimbra`.

**Do not forget to make backups of *.in-files* BEFORE any modifications!!!** Because they're templates, you may unintentionally broke something with just  one extra character or punctuation mark.

Comment: Hope, it will help you.

Comment: Remember that many of these templates are overrun when Zimbra is upgraded. You will have to re-check these files after upgrade.

Comment: @vtorhonen, you're right. That's why before every upgrade I made rsync-ed complete copy of /opt/zimbra to have a possibility to compare the templates and config in order to re-enter my changes.

Comment: Or I save my edited .in under .in.my extension to easen the comparison process.